# How to disable swipe gesture in SFSafariViewController after presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have written the below code to disable the swipe pop gesture in SFSafariViewController. But it is not working.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

I have also added the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return YES;
}
```

But it is never called. Please help me out to disable the pop gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Please override presentationControllerShouldDismiss and return false in that method.

```
- (BOOL)presentationControllerShouldDismiss:(UIPresentationController *)presentationController{
   return NO;
}
```

or can you try setting the modalInPresentation parameter to YES for the SFSafariViewController object? because as per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-modalinpresentation?language=objc) it says...

> The default value of this property is NO. When you set it to YES,
> UIKit ignores events outside the view controller's bounds and prevents
> the interactive dismissal of the view controller while it is onscreen.

Comment: I have inherit the SFSafariViewController and write - (BOOL)presentationControllerShouldDismiss:(UIPresentationController *)presentationController{
   return NO;
}
but this delegate method is not called.

Comment: Ok then try setting modalInPresentation=NO; in the inherited class.